# Pre-compile textual replacement macro with arguments

Tags: macros, precompile, specman, e

I am trying to create some kind of a `dut_error` wrapper. Something that will take some arguments and construct them in a specific way to a `dut_error`.

I can't use a method to replace the calls to `dut_error` because to my understanding after `check that ... then ... else` can only come a `dut_error` (or `dut_errorf`). And indeed if I try to do something like:

```
my_dut_error(arg1: string, arg2: string) is {
    dut_error("first argument is ", arg, " and second argument is ", arg2);
};

check that FALSE else my_dut_error("check1", "check2");
```

I get an error:

```
*** Error: Unrecognized exp
 [Unrecognized expression 'FALSE else my_dut_error("check1", "check2")']
     at line x in main.e
         check that FALSE else my_dut_error("check1", "check2");
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So I thought about defining a macro to simply do a textual replace from my wrapper to an actual `dut_error`:

```
define <my_dut_error'exp> "my_dut_error(<arg1'name>, <arg2'name>)" as {
    dut_error("first argument is ", <arg1'name>, " and second argument is ", <arg2'name>)
};
```

But got the same error.

Then I read about the preprocessor directive `#define` so tried:

```
#define my_dut_error(arg1, arg2) dut_error("first argument is ", arg, " and second argument is ", arg2)
```

But that just gave a syntax error.

***How can I define a pre-compiled textual replacement macro that takes arguments***, similar to C?

---

The reason I want to do that is to achieve some sort of an "interface" to the `dut_error` so all errors have a consistent structure. This way, different people writing different errors will only pass the arguments necessary by that interface and internally an appropriate message will be created.

Answer (score 1):

not sure i understood what you want to do in the wrapper, but perhaps you can achieve what you want by using the dut_error_struct.

it has set of api, which you can use as hooks (do something when the error is caught) and to query about the specific error.
for example:

```
extend dut_error_struct {
   pre_error() is also {
      if source_method_name() == "post_generate" and 
         source_struct() is a BLUE packet {
         out("\nProblem in generation? ", source_location());
         // do something for error during generation
    };
    write() is first {
       if get_mesage() ~ "AHB Error..." {
           ahb_monitor::increase_errors();
       };
    }; 
    
};
```

Comment: That looks like a very good option for what I need. Is there a way to extract the arguments passed to the `dut_error` this way? See my edited question for clarification

Answer (score 1):

dut_error accepts one parameter, one string. but you can decide of a "separator", that will define two parts to the message.
e.g. - instruct people to write "XXX" in the message, before "first arg" and "second arg".

```
check that legal else dut_error("ONE thing", "XXX", "another thing");
check that x < 7 else dut_error("failure ", "XXX", "of x not 7 but is ", x);


extend dut_error_struct {
    write() is first {
        var message_parts := str_split(get_message(), "XXX");
    
    if message_parts.size() == 2 {
        out ("First part of message is ", message_parts[0],
             "\nand second part of message is ", message_parts[1]
            );
    };
};
```

Comment: From what I understand (not a specman expert), the `get_message()` returns the full message that will be printed. i.e. even if I pass multiple arguments, they will be concatenated to one string and returned through `get_message()`. I would like to be able to get those arguments separately, before they are concatenated. And better of course without forcing a separator argument to be passed. Isn't there a simple way to get all the arguments?

Comment: Thanks alot for your answers! They helped me in the thought process on this problem and I feel this question might be an XY problem and I was asking about the wrong thing here. I formulated another question more specific to what I need so if you have an answer to that it would be great. It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702814/how-to-get-all-arguments-passed-to-a-dut-error-call-through-the-dut-error-struct)

Answer (score 0):

I could get pretty close to what I want using the `dut_errorf` method combined with a preprocessor directive defining the format string:

```
#define DUT_FORMAT "first argument is %s and second argument is %s"

check that FALSE else dut_errorf(DUT_FORMAT, "check1", "check2");
```

but I would still prefer a way that doesn't require this `DUT_FORMAT` directive and instead uses `dut_error_struct` or something similar.